# SSRS report parameters dependent on each other

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report with four parameters. Each parameter is multiselect and text type. When I select a value in one parameter, the values other parameters should change based on selected value. Its like parameters are forward dependent and backward dependent. How can I achieve this.

Comment: your current code please?

Answer (score 3):

This feature is called [Cascading Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169.aspx) and short answer to your question is - *backward dependencies are allowed but forward dependencies are not*.

I would describe this on short example.

Suppose you have a report with two parameters **Dealer** and **Region** - both are text and multiselect and you want to have a dependency from **Dealer** to **Region**, i.e. if you select region(s) from **Region** parameter first then dealers list in **Dealer** parameter dynamically changes to show only those dealers which is related to selected **Region**.

[image]

To acheive this you need to define three datasets and two parameters:

- **Main** dataset for Main report with one parameter `@dealername`,
- **Dealers** dataset - values source for `@dealername` parameter with one parameter - `@region` (backward dependency) and
- **Regions** dataset - values source for `@region` parameter without any parameter

In other words approach then

```
MainReport <---is filtered by--- Dealers <---is filtered by--- Regions
```

would work well, but if you try to add forward dependency from **Regions** dataset to **Dealers** - i.e. add `@dealername` parameter to **Regions**, then you'll get an error message -

**Forward dependencies are not valid** because by doing so you'll create a circular reference which can not be resolved.

[image]